# Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions, contacts, android-contacts

I am getting this error when I am trying to read contacts from phone and I included `READ_CONTACTS` permission in Manifest file. And the strange thing is that it was working fine in *Eclipse* but when I converted my project to *Gradle* and run it in *Android Studio* I'm getting this error.

logcat says:

> Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{302f069 29282:com.GP/u0a322} (pid=29282, uid=10322) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS

here is the Manifest code:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <!-- Read Contacts from phone -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.read_contacts" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.read_phone_state" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

Comment: Is anyone getting this issue on API 29 (Android 10)? I am getting this same exception, but apps -> my app -> permissions -> contacts is allowed. UPDATE: I denied the permission then re-added it. Now it works. Android OS defect? Anyone else experiencing the same issue?

Answer (score 61):

Due to the Marshmallow update Requesting Permissions at Run Time the read contact permission not work. The sample code is

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // The ListView
    private ListView lstNames;

    // Request code for READ_CONTACTS. It can be any number > 0.
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find the list view
        this.lstNames = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstNames);

        // Read and show the contacts
        showContacts();
    }

    /**
     * Show the contacts in the ListView.
     */
    private void showContacts() {
        // Check the SDK version and whether the permission is already granted or not.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
            //After this point you wait for callback in onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]) overriden method
        } else {
            // Android version is lesser than 6.0 or the permission is already granted.
            List<String> contacts = getContactNames();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contacts);
            lstNames.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                           int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission is granted
                showContacts();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Until you grant the permission, we canot display the names", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read the name of all the contacts.
     *
     * @return a list of names.
     */
    private List<String> getContactNames() {
        List<String> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        // Get the ContentResolver
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        // Get the Cursor of all the contacts
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        // Move the cursor to first. Also check whether the cursor is empty or not.
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            // Iterate through the cursor
            do {
                // Get the contacts name
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                contacts.add(name);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // Close the curosor
        cursor.close();

        return contacts;
    }
}
```

The sample screenshots :
[image]
[image]

I got the following source code from [here](http://www.javahelps.com/2015/10/android-60-runtime-permission-model.html)

Comment: I tried doing this still my exception remains same. It works on 4.4.2 device i got the contact list but when I run the app on 6.0 it crashes with same exception. @krishnan

Answer (score 5):

My issue was that I was using a Marshmallow emulator and that has made some changes as to how we request permissions from user. Hence it kept asking for the permissions even after adding them. http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: i'm having the same issue, I have already specified <uses-permission> but even then it keeps asking

Answer (score 4):

The new run-time permission scheme is used only if the app's **targetSdkVersion** (specified in the manifest) is 23 or higher.  So, one way to avoid the issue is to make the **targetSdkVersion** lower than 23.  See the description here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: This answer cannot be an answer anymore since Google play is asking for min value 26 of targetSdkVersion.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play restricts the use of high risk or sensitive permissions, including the SMS or Call Log permission groups. So in short, even if you ask permission at runtime, there's a high chance that your app will not be allowed in Google Play.

You can apply for an exception though. Google Play will review the request and grant exceptions on a case by case basis.
The criteria for allowing an exception are mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // The ListView
    private ListView lstNames;

    // Request code for READ_CONTACTS. It can be any number > 0.
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find the list view
        this.lstNames = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstNames);

        // Read and show the contacts
        showContacts();
    }

    /**
     * Show the contacts in the ListView.
     */
    private void showContacts() {
        // Check the SDK version and whether the permission is already granted or not.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
            //After this point you wait for callback in onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]) overriden method
        } else {
            // Android version is lesser than 6.0 or the permission is already granted.
            List<String> contacts = getContactNames();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contacts);
            lstNames.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                           int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission is granted
                showContacts();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Until you grant the permission, we canot display the names", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read the name of all the contacts.
     *
     * @return a list of names.
     */
    private List<String> getContactNames() {
        List<String> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        // Get the ContentResolver
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        // Get the Cursor of all the contacts
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        // Move the cursor to first. Also check whether the cursor is empty or not.
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            // Iterate through the cursor
            do {
                // Get the contacts name
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                contacts.add(name);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // Close the curosor
        cursor.close();

        return contacts;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

According to Google's Documentation on requesting permission, here's the thing to bear in mind when you're handling it.

> For example, suppose you list both READ_CONTACTS and WRITE_CONTACTS in
>   your app manifest.
>
> If you request READ_CONTACTS and the user grants
>   the permission, and you then request WRITE_CONTACTS, the system
>   immediately grants you that permission without interacting with the
>   user.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: He is asking something entirely different.