# Getting phone number from contacts using ContentProvider - Android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am making a small app where I can get the contacts of my phone using a content provider and display them in a listview as illustrated.

[image]

I want to select a row of the listview and automically make a phone call to that specific contact. I tried some things,but they don't work. Any ideas? Here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor c = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},
            null, null, null);

    List<String> contacts = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            contacts.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main, contacts);
    setListAdapter(adapter);



}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

      //The answer should be inside here.

  }
}
```

Comment: do not create a POJO class, do not iterate over the `Cursor` in a loop, do not use `ArrayAdapter`, what to do instead? use `SimpleCursorAdapter`, that's all

Comment: @pskink Good call. I always forget about the CursorAdapters, for some reason. Never used 'em much,

Comment: @MikeM. at least you KNOW that using them with a `Cursor` based data model is much better than using POJO/loop/ArrayAdapter, 95% guys here DONT and what is worse they are so stubborn in using bad practices...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, ensure that you have added the Permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

**UPDATE**:
On Android 6 and higher stating the permission in the manifest is not enough, you have to explicitly ask user for granting permission on reading contacts otherwise, you will get an exception. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915919/permission-denial-opening-provider-com-android-providers-contacts-contactsprovi) for more details.

Then you can loop through your phone contacts like this:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null); 
while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
    String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( 
    String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

    if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) { 
        // You know it has a number so now query it like this
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId, null, null); 
        while (phones.moveToNext()) { 
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));                 
        } 
        phones.close(); 
    }

    Cursor emails = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null); 

    while (emails.moveToNext()) { 
        // This would allow you get several email addresses 
        String emailAddress = emails.getString( 
        emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA)); 
    } 

    emails.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Theo for Response.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
private void doMagicContacts() {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
            .query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);

    if (cursor == null) {
        return;
    }

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    do {
        String name = cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String id = cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.NAME_RAW_CONTACT_ID));

        Cursor phones = getContentResolver()
                .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.RAW_CONTACT_ID+" = " + id,
                        null,
                        null);
        if (phones != null) {
            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(
                        phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                Log.d(TAG, "doMagicContacts: " + name + " " + phoneNumber);
            }
            phones.close();
        }

    } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    cursor.close();
}
```