# How to read call log history of a device in android in 6.0

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, android-permissions, calllog

My main aim of the app is to read the call history of the device and show it to the user using recyclerview and cardview. But When i run on **marshmallow** device app getting force close. Here is the code that i have used to read call history and the error that i got, when i run on 6.0

My MainActivity look like:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Callbacks {
    ArrayList<CallLogItem> mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calllog);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        getCallDetails();

    }

    private void getCallDetails() {
        String strOrder = CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
        Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, strOrder);
        int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String phNum = managedCursor.getString(number);
            String callTypeCode = managedCursor.getString(type);
            String strcallDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
            Date callDate = new Date(Long.valueOf(strcallDate));
            String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
            String callType = null;
            int callcode = Integer.parseInt(callTypeCode);
            switch (callcode) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    callType = "Outgoing";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    callType = "Incoming";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    callType = "Missed";
                    break;
            }

            CallLogItem callLogItem = new CallLogItem();
            callLogItem.setPhoneNumber(phNum);
            callLogItem.setCallDate(String.valueOf(callDate));
            callLogItem.setCallType(callType);
            callLogItem.setCallDuration(callDuration);
            mItems.add(callLogItem);

            mAdapter = new CallLogAdapter(mItems, this);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        }
        managedCursor.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCustomClick(CallLogItem callLogItem) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + callLogItem.getPhoneNumber(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCustomLongClick(CallLogItem callLogItem) {

    }}
```

My Adapter Class look like:

```
    public class CallLogAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CallLogAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<CallLogItem> mItems;
    private Callbacks mCallbacks;

    public CallLogAdapter(ArrayList<CallLogItem> mItems, Callbacks callbacks) {
        this.mItems = mItems;
        this.mCallbacks = callbacks;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.bookmark_card_item, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        CallLogItem callLogItem = mItems.get(position);
        viewHolder.phoneNumber.setText("Phone Number: " + callLogItem.getPhoneNumber());
        viewHolder.callDuration.setText("Call Duration(In Sec): " + callLogItem.getCallDuration());
        viewHolder.callDate.setText("Call Date: " + callLogItem.getCallDate());
        viewHolder.callType.setText("Call Type: " + callLogItem.getCallType());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

        public View view;
        public TextView phoneNumber, callDuration, callDate, callType;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.view = itemView;
            phoneNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
            callDuration = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.callDuration);
            callDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.callDate);
            callType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.callType);
            view.setOnLongClickListener(this);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);

        }


        // onCustomClick Listener for view
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            CallLogItem callLogItem = mItems.get(position);

            mCallbacks.onCustomClick(callLogItem);
        }


        //onLongClickListener for view
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            CallLogItem callLogItem = mItems.get(position);

            mCallbacks.onCustomLongClick(callLogItem);
            return true;
        }
    }}
```

My POJO class look like:

```
public class CallLogItem {

    private String phoneNumber;
    private String callType;
    private String callDate;
    private String callDuration;

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getCallType() {
        return callType;
    }

    public void setCallType(String callType) {
        this.callType = callType;
    }

    public String getCallDate() {
        return callDate;
    }

    public void setCallDate(String callDate) {
        this.callDate = callDate;
    }

    public String getCallDuration() {
        return callDuration;
    }

    public void setCallDuration(String callDuration) {
        this.callDuration = callDuration;
    }}

My CallbackClass look like

    public interface Callbacks {
    void onCustomClick(CallLogItem callLogItem);
    void onCustomLongClick(CallLogItem callLogItem);}
```

**Error**

```
   Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: 
       opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider                                                                           from ProcessRecord{bf7427a 7579:karthik.callloghistory/u0a525} (pid=7579, uid=10525) requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG or android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG
                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3860)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5055)
                                                                      at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2025)
                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1517)
                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:482)
                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:441)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:2033)
                                                                      at karthik.callloghistory.MainActivity.getCallDetails(MainActivity.java:39)
                                                                      at karthik.callloghistory.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6583)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1114)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2531)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1493) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
```

Here is my manifest file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="karthik.callloghistory">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915919/permission-denial-opening-provider-com-android-providers-contacts-contactsprovi)

Comment: I need to get call log history, not to read phone contacts

Comment: add runtime permission for READ_CALL_LOG.

Comment: Implement Runtime Permissions before calling `getCallDetails()` method. Adding `READ_CALL_LOG` to Manifest alone is not sufficient on 23+.